# Trying to use Count (*) with DISTINCT on INNER JOIN

Tags: sql, sql-server

Looking for a little help, I basically just need to return a count from the following query:

```sql
USE MediaProcessingQueue;

SELECT DISTINCT dbo.MessageQueue.messageId,dbo.MessageQueue.state,dbo.MessageQueue.wsaMessageId,dbo.MessageQueue.refId,dbo.StatusUpdate.messageId
FROM dbo.MessageQueue
INNER JOIN dbo.StatusUpdate
ON dbo.MessageQueue.messageId=dbo.StatusUpdate.messageId
WHERE dbo.MessageQueue.state ='1' AND dbo.StatusUpdate.percentComplete > 12
```

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: Use select @@ROWCOUNT after your query

Answer (score 0):

Put the `Count` around the `DISTINCT` columns.

```
Use MediaProcessingQueue
GO
select Count(DISTINCT dbo.MessageQueue.messageId,dbo.MessageQueue.state,dbo.MessageQueue.wsaMessageId,dbo.MessageQueue.refId,dbo.StatusUpdate.messageId)
FROM dbo.MessageQueue
INNER JOIN dbo.StatusUpdate
ON dbo.MessageQueue.messageId=dbo.StatusUpdate.messageId
WHERE dbo.MessageQueue.state ='1' AND dbo.StatusUpdate.percentComplete > 12
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Count(*)
FROM   (
        <insert your existing query here>
       ) As a_subquery
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get ONLY count use this

```
Select Count(DISTINCT dbo.MessageQueue.messageId,dbo.MessageQueue.state,dbo.MessageQueue.wsaMessageId,dbo.MessageQueue.refId,dbo.StatusUpdate.messageId)
```

If you want to get count as well as the query output use this

```
select @@ROWCOUNT
```

Next line after the select query.

Answer (score 0):

You could also do:

`Count(*)` or `Sum(1)` with a `Group By`

```
USE MediaProcessingQueue;

SELECT Sum(1)
  FROM dbo.MessageQueue
    INNER JOIN dbo.StatusUpdate
      ON dbo.MessageQueue.messageId=dbo.StatusUpdate.messageId
  WHERE dbo.MessageQueue.state ='1' AND dbo.StatusUpdate.percentComplete > 12
  GROUP BY dbo.MessageQueue.messageId, dbo.MessageQueue.state, dbo.MessageQueue.wsaMessageId, dbo.MessageQueue.refId, dbo.StatusUpdate.messageId
```